# Algorithm problem: find the longest pair name chain

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Assume that there is a list of strings, like `[['Jason, Nick']['Nick, Bob']['Bob', 'Mac']]`. We want to find the longest length of pair chain that the first name of the second list is equal to the last name of the first list. For the example above, the max length is 3.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a minute to read [ask].

Comment: Can the chain contain non-consecutive elements? Like in case `[[A, B], [B, C], [F, D], [C, D]]` the max length is 3: `[A, B], [B, C], [C, D]`?

Comment: @AlexRudenko Yeah, It can. And not in order, Like it can be [C,D],[A,B],[A,C][B,C], max = 3

Comment: You can rethink each pair of names as an undirected (or directed? not too clear from the examples) edge between two nodes. From here, the problem is reduced to finding the longest path in a graph, which can be solved via depth/breadth first search.

Comment: @wLui155 each pair of names is a directed edge (as the position of the names differ between the start and end of the edge). Solving for longest path is easy if the graph has no cycle, else it's [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem#NP-hardness)